# Upsampling very large data sets efficiently

Tags: filters, resampling

I have gigabytes worth of seismic ground data, that I wish to upsample by a factor of 2 or 3. I wanted to ask what efficient way might there be for me to upsample such a big file? Is there a way to break it down and do it in mini-files? (I am using MATLAB for my software, I think the resample command might take too long though). Thank you.

Comment: How good of resampling do you need? Simple linear interpolation between points can work if you don't need a high-quality resampler.

Comment: @JasonR I need a 'good enough' resampler. I am not sure how to be more specific on it though, or how to quantify that. Just as one might resample a vector by a factor of 2 or 3, so too, I need to resample this vector with the same expectations.

Comment: ''Good enough" will depend on the highest frequency components in your data set, and how accurately you want these frequencies reproduced or lack of aliased frequency content above them introduced.  Also on the S/N ratio of the original data and the desired result.

Comment: @hotpaw2 The worst case in my data set, involves frequencies that are close to nyquist, and so yes, I would very much like to maintain them. For example, with a sampling rate of 50 KHz, I have some signals in the 45 KHz range that I want to maintain nicely.

Comment: I hope you mean: "...with a sampling rate of **100** KHz, I have some signals in the 45 KHz range that I want to maintain..." ?

Comment: Can you clarify *why* you want to upsample the data ? You don't gain any new information of course, and you double or treble your storage requirements. If you need upsampled data then why not just upsample on-the-fly when you read the data from disk ?

Comment: @PaulR Sorry yes, I meant 100 KHz. We have seismic box sampling at that rate. The upsampling is simply because we have an old box that can only process data at double or triple the sampling rate. (I have no power over that).

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond: Can't you just interpret the results of the old box as if the sampling rate were different?

Comment: @endolith Not really, we have to place it there at a new sample rate and process accordingly.